# Apple sign in, authorize method returns name only first time

Tags: web, apple-sign-in

Implementing Apple sign in in a web app (old fashion ASP.NET, but it doesn't matter - the question can be treated as simple HTML/JS POC), calling method authorize on Apple endpoint:

```
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&response_type=code%20id_token&state=...&response_mode=form_post&scope=name%20email
```

I want to get the user's first and last name.
Method returns something like this:
{

```
   "state": "xxx",
   "code": "yyy",
   "id_token": "zzz",
   "user": {
        "name": {
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Doe"
        },
        "email":"example@privaterelay.appleid.com"
    }
}
```

id_token is JWT which consists of user's apple ID and email, there is no data regarding name or surname.

As you can see, I can get name and surname from the *user* property. That's the only way known to me.

The problem is, Apple returns this data only the first time I request it. It's not a bug, it's a feature: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple :

> Important
>
> Apple only returns the user object the first time the user authorizes
> the app. Persist this information from your app; subsequent
> authorization requests won’t contain the user object.

So I store this data for later in the workflow, I will store it in database.

**Now my problem/question:**

When user deletes their account, I delete all their data from db (I have to, because of the contract, law etc).

When the user registers again through Apple sign in, I ping Apple endpoint, and I don't get user data (including name and surname) any more (because of the Apple policy quoted above)!

What should I do to get it?

Comment: Did you fund only this one problem? Second is that user post filed can not be trusted. After redirection to redirect_uri you can trust email just from id_token filed but you must verify id_token integrity https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/fetch_apple_s_public_key_for_verifying_token_signature OR you can request  https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token and id_token from this server-to-server request can be directly trusted without additional verification. But as said problem is user filed which can be faked by user/attacker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doing apple sign-in back-end part, faced the similar issue.

**For IOS 13+**

- SDK provides apple user uuid, email and name for the first authorize request.
- We are mapping this unique apple_user_uuid with the profile details in DB.
  (In case of request failures, you can ask back-end to put this in queue and app should keep this in cache until back-end call is successful).

**For ANDROID/WEB Flow/IOS Below 13**

- For the first time in apple callback, it sends us the name with a one time code (5 minute expiry).
- Using this code when we call token API, it provides us id_token JWT.
- In token the subject is apple_user_uuid.
- Persist it in the same table.

So now in back-end you will always have email,firstName, lastName tagged with apple_user_uuid, which remains constant for an apple id.

And don't delete this mapping if the user deletes your account. Until apple provides a fix.

Comment: Yeah, not really answer I was hoping for but close enough. I need to give task to BE team to do this, and I expect them to roll their eyes :D

Comment: Anyway to turn on a  gettin name and email for a particular user everytime for testing?  A real pain to test when you have to keep creating apple ids.

Comment: @DavidBrenchley when you first sign in with Apple ID, it registers the service in your Apple ID account.  Login to your Apple ID account, under security ->  manage apps and websites -> click on service and "stop using Apple ID".  Next authorize request for that user will provide name and email again.